# Función "Calcular" para botón Tkinter que sobreescriba dato anterior - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo este trozo código, que define una función en Python para calcular la eficacia de un proceso termodinámico, obteniendo valores de 3 Entry para luego mostrar el resultado en otros dos (como decimal y como porcentaje).

```
def CalcularEficacia():
    h5=float(C1.get())
    h4=float(C2.get())
    h2=float(C3.get())
    eficacia = (h5-h2)/(h4-h2)
    porcentaje = eficacia*100
    efi = round(eficacia,4)
    por = round(porcentaje,4)
    pors= str(por)
    C4.insert(0,efi)
    C5.insert(0,pors+"%")
```

Esta función la asocié a un botón "Calcular"

```
B1 = Button(ventana,text="Calcular Ɛ",command=CalcularEficacia,width=8,height=2)
```

Mi consulta es que al presionar el botón, muestra lo que quiero, pero luego al cambiar los datos y volver a presionar el botón, el dato calculado anterior no se reemplaza por el nuevo, sino que el dato anterior lo desplaza a la derecha y se inserta el nuevo al principio del Entry. ¿Qué debería cambiar para que esto no suceda? De antemano, muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método insert del entry, como dice su nombre, inserta texto en el entry, no lo reemplaza.

La solución sería eliminar el contenido anterior del entry con su método delete. El comando que necesitaremos es `entry.delete(0, "end")` donde 0 es el incio del texto del entry y "end" su final.

El código de tu función debería de quedar así:

```
def CalcularEficacia():
    h5=float(C1.get())
    h4=float(C2.get())
    h2=float(C3.get())
    eficacia = (h5-h2)/(h4-h2)
    porcentaje = eficacia*100
    efi = round(eficacia,4)
    por = round(porcentaje,4)
    pors= str(por)

    C4.delete(0, "end")
    C5.delete(0, "end")

    C4.insert(0,efi)
    C5.insert(0,pors+"%")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha sido de utilidad para lo que requería, al final resultó ser más simple de lo que pensaba. ¡Te lo agradezco mucho!

Comment: Me alegro de haber ayudado c: Recuerda que puedes aceptar mi respuesta si te fue util!